# Cast LinkedList<type> to LinkedList <superType> (java)

Tags: java, casting, linked-list

I've got an Interface SenseFitSensor. Class HardwareSensor implements it (future implements could be eg DummySensor).

Now I've got a method which requires `LinkedList<SenseFitSensor>`.

```
public ExerciseLearner(LinkedList<SenseFitSensor> sensorList){
```

I cannot provvide it with a `LinkedList<HardwareSensor>`, because LinkedList cannot be cast to `SensefitSensor`.

What does work is

```
LinkedList<SenseFitSensor> senseFitSensors = new LinkedList<SenseFitSensor>(hardwareSensors);
    learner = new ExerciseLearner(senseFitSensors);
```

But a new linkedlist is created each time. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use bounded wild cards

```
public ExerciseLearner(LinkedList<? extends SenseFitSensor> sensorList){
```

---

References

- [Upper Bounded Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html)

Comment: Perfect, thanks. The documentation will help me in similar situtions